# access variable defined in Javascript (jQuery) in php

Tags: php

In my php file the javascript/html code is written using echo. I would like to access the image that is going to be placed in "place1" div in javascript and pass it to php.

here is my code:

```
 // create a placeholder for an image- user is going to drag and drop an image here
echo "<div id= 'place1' class = 'place'></div>";
echo '<button id="apply" name="save" type="submit">Apply Changes</button>';
echo '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>';
//javascipt code to find the source of that image
echo 
'<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#apply").click(function() {
            var frame = $("#place1").children("img").attr("src");
            $.ajax({
                url: "thumbnails.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: frame
            });
        });
    });
</script>';

 // access frame variable (image source) in php ??? not sure how to do this part..
$frame = $_post['frame'];
```

Comment: What is the value of var frame (in the jQuery section)

Answer (score 0):

in your jquery you must use a key/value pair when sending `data`:

`key=value`

With that in mind, for your `data` that you are sending, your are using the variable `frame`, but `frame` does not have the key/value pair. It should be:

```
var frame = "frame="+$("#place1").children("img").attr("src");
```

This will now allow you to capture the variable in PHP:

`$frame = $_POST['frame']`